# Android - TextWatcher is invoked once for each character in pasted text

Tags: android, count, character, paste, textwatcher

I've added a TextWatcher to an EditText and am listening for changes in the text via the onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) method. When I paste text that has say 10 characters, into this EditText, onTextChanged() gets called 10 times, once for each character in the text I pasted, from left to right. I want onTextChanged() to be called only once after all 10 characters have been pasted into the EditText. I'm sure this should be possible, because otherwise what's the point in having the "count" param if it's always going to be 1?

Comment: My bad! onTextChanged() gets called 1,2,or 3 times depending on where the new text is being pasted. Once if there was no text in the EditText where the text is being pasted. Twice if the new textis being pasted at the beginning or end of original text. And thrice if the new text is being pasted somewhere in between the original text. The reason is if a paste is happening adjacent to another character, Android inserts a space in between. The space inserts happen before the actual text is inserted. So a more appropriate question would be if there is a way to prevent spaces from being inserted?

Answer (score 2):

`count` won't always be 1: for instance, if you select and delete a block of text or if you choose an autocomplete option.

In any case, the details of whether pasting happens in one chunk or one character at a time is an implementation detail, and if you rely on either behavior it's likely your app will break in the future.

Comment: Yeah, count will be 0 in case of a delete operation. I'm trying to do something when the paste is complete, so it does matter to me. And I'd expect the platform to be consistent in its behavior.

Comment: There's some functionality in the paste operation that inserts whitespaces before and after the text as part of the paste operation. Caution when setting text in the handlers, as if text is set empty, it might cause this to crash when it attempts to insert text that has changed from what was expected. This insertion of whitespace before/after pasted text also causes additional firings of the onTextChanged (and other) events.

Answer (score -1):

Try using afterTextChanged it will only get one call

Comment: Not true. afterTextChanged() gets called right after onTextChanged() is called each time.